# How to fix: Can't resolve all parameters for ContactField: (?, ?, ?) : ionic-native/contacts error

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

For those who try to use cordova-plugin-contacts of @ionic-native/contacts and get the error "Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ContactField: (?, ?, ?)." on app launching.

I found the solution:

In the app.module.ts you need to only import Contacts and put only Contacts in the providers:

```
import { Contacts } from "@ionic-native/contacts/ngx";

providers: [
    Contacts
  ]
```

Then just use it like in the documentation like the example:

```
import { Contacts, Contact, ContactField, ContactName } from '@ionic-native/contacts/ngx';

constructor(private contacts: Contacts) { }

let contact: Contact = this.contacts.create();

contact.name = new ContactName(null, 'Smith', 'John');
contact.phoneNumbers = [new ContactField('mobile', '6471234567')];
contact.save().then(
  () => console.log('Contact saved!', contact),
  (error: any) => console.error('Error saving contact.', error)
);
```

I hope it will help ;)